# <ui:inputradio is allowing to select multiple records

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience

I have used  `"<ui:inputRadio>"`  tag for selecting the one record in the list of records.It is working fine when the all the records are loaded in one page. Its allowing to select multiple records when the records loaded with pagination. I mean,  its not allowing to select multiple records of same page but its allowing to select multiple records of different page of same list.

```
 <ui:inputRadio text="{!sAidx}" name="Row" value= "{!record.isSelected}" change="{!c.onGroup}"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that could happen depending on how the pagination was implemented. HTML itself can't directly figure out that you have unrendered rows of data. In your change handler, you would probably want to check all records not on the current page and set isSelected to false. There could be other ways to deal with this too, like hidden radios or such, but just handling it in your controller/helper methods would probably be most efficient.